# Unable to apt-get after editing firewall settings

Tags: apt, firewall

I am currently testing out the Tomcat on `apache` from turnkey Linux and I am unable to run any `apt-get` commands.

The problem started when I edited the firewall settings from the `webmin`.

How can I get this to work again?

Firewall settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but about port 3306: are you sure you want to let MySQL connections in from the outside? Generally you want to allow only localhost connections.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Oh I see. Im new at firewall configurtion and stuff. What would you recommend? I need this to function as a normal website with access to a database of movies to be displayed on the wesite

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` may use FTP, in addition to HTTP, but you aren't letting FTP through the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept *under OUTPUT* **destination** port 80 (http), 21 (ftp), and possibly 8080.

Also, I am not familiar with the Webmin interface, but you need to make sure all "established, related" connections are allowed, because `apt` will use a random high number port locally, and that's where data will be received.  The "established, related" rule is not explicit in you configuration, so either it's implicit in Webmin, or you'll have to add it.